# Understanding Android Visualizer FFT output

Tags: java, android, audio, data-visualization

I'm trying to create a bar graph of the frequency spectrum and I am using the android Visualizer API. I set an onFftDataCapure listener and am successfully receiving a byte array. The byte array appears to be more than just amplitude x frequency, lots of near min/max values that don't make sense. Looking at the documentation - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Visualizer.html#getFft(byte%5B%5D) it describes:

> The capture returns the real and imaginary parts of a number of frequency points
>
> The layout in the returned byte array is as follows:
>
> - n is the capture size returned by getCaptureSize()
> - Rfk, Ifk are respectively the real and imaginary parts of the kth frequency    component
> - If Fs is the sampling frequency retuned by    getSamplingRate() the kth frequency is: k * Fs / n

This is my first time looking at audio analysis so i'm not sure what any of the documentation means or how to use it. I tried graphing just the even or odd indexes (real / imaginary?) but that didn't output anything I was expecting.

Here is an example emission of the byte array:

```
 [218,255,12,37,0,11,253,247,246,2,2,5,253,255,0,1,253,255,254,4,2,4,254,4,0,1,1,1,255,0,255,0,255,2,0,0,255,255,1,255,253,1,253,252,251,252,253,253,1,0,1,2,253,2,0,0,0,1,255,0,1,255,0,1,0,255,0,1,0,0,255,0,1,255,0,2,0,255,254,0,254,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,254,0,254,255,255,0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255,255,255,0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255,255,255,255,255,0]
```

How can I turn this into an array where the index is the frequency range and the value is the amplitude?

Comment: Look at the code snippet in the documentation. What you want is the array called `magnitudes`.

Comment: I had tried that but implemented it in c# (this is a android plugin), doing it Java side seemed to work, thanks!. What does the phases array represent?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_(waves))